# selectedDraggable in image preview

Tags: javascript, jquery, image

I would like to know how I can do selectedDraggable on my image preview what I want to do is intergrade  "selectedDraggable" to image preview so I can be able to delete any image I select without erasing all the images in preview container. for some reason my code is not working I cannot click [X] to delete the images please help thank you

```js
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("image-input");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);

function previewImages() {
  var fileList = this.files;

  var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    var imgEl =  $('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" />');
    $('<div class="preview-area"/>').append(imgEl).appendTo('body').draggable();
    imgEl.load(function() {
      $(this).resizable();
    });
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
  }


}
$('.remove-img').click(function (e) {
    $(this).parent().find('img').not(this).remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script  
 src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
 <link rel="stylesheet"
href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet"
 href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script><script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>

<div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
  <input type="file" class="dimmy" id="image-input" multiple />
<span class="remove-img">[x]</span>  
 <span id="image" class="preview-area"style="height:100px; width:200px;" ></span>
</div>
```

```
var count = 1;
var selectedDraggable;

ko.bindingHandlers.draggable={
init: function(element, valueAccessor, allBindingsAccessor, viewModel) {
    $(element).draggable();
    $(element).addClass('item' + count);
    count++;
    $(element).on('click', function () {
        selectedDraggable = $(this);
    })
}
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code `$(this).parent()` will return `#draggableHelper`, but the images are appended to `body`, this means `$(this).parent().find('img')` will by empty. To solve that you can append your images to `#draggableHelper`:

```js
var inputLocalFont = document.getElementById("image-input");
inputLocalFont.addEventListener("change", previewImages, false);

function previewImages() {
  var fileList = this.files;

  var anyWindow = window.URL || window.webkitURL;

  for (var i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
    var objectUrl = anyWindow.createObjectURL(fileList[i]);
    var imgEl = $('<img src="' + objectUrl + '" />');
    $('<div class="preview-area"/>').append('<a class="remove-img"> &times; </a>').append(imgEl).appendTo('body')
      .draggable();
    //^ change to this
    imgEl.load(function() {
      $(this).resizable();
    });
    window.URL.revokeObjectURL(fileList[i]);
  }


}
$('body').on('click', '.remove-img', function(e) {
  e.stopPropagation();
  var parent = $(this).parents('.preview-area');
  parent.find('img').resizable('destroy');
  parent.draggable('destroy').remove();
});
```

```css
.remove-img {
  position: relative;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  width: 25px;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #f00;
  font-size: 22px;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  display: block;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/2.3.0/knockout-min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" />
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.2/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<script src="http://circletype.labwire.ca/js/circletype.js"></script>
<script src="http://tympanus.net/Development/Arctext/js/jquery.arctext.js"></script>

<div id="draggableHelper" style="display:inline-block">
  <input type="file" class="dimmy" id="image-input" multiple />
  <span id="image" class="preview-area" style="height:100px; width:200px;"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: how can I delete one by one not all at the same time?

Comment: Please check out the updated answer! It will show a close button above any added image.

Comment: amazing thank you you're the best thank you for taking the time in helping me