# combine two different scripts

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, draggable, resizable

i found this [selectedDraggable in image preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423755/selecteddraggable-in-image-preview) this is exactly what i need for deleting my images and the draggable and resizable works great but their is a small problem the code that i have will allow html2canvas to save the container as an image on my desktop i was wondering if it was possible to combine these two codes? all i need from [selectedDraggable in image preview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38423755/selecteddraggable-in-image-preview) is the delete image, resizable, and draggable to be added to this script

```
<script>
// External added
jQuery(download).ready(function () {
    jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").hide();
    jQuery(".out-put-img2").hide();
    jQuery("#imajes45").change(function () {
        var selected = jQuery('#imajes45').val();
        if (selected == "new-upload") {
            jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").show();
        } else {
            jQuery(".file-upload-wrapper1").hide();
        }
    });

    //File
    function readURL(input) {

        if (input.files && input.files[0]) {
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = function (e) {
                jQuery(".out-put-img2").show();
                $('#output2').attr('src', e.target.result);
 //                   / $('.append-img').append('src', e.target.result);
            }
            reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);
        }
    }
    jQuery("#upload-img2").change(function () {
        readURL(this);

    $(".dragbal1").draggable();
 $(".out-put-img2").resizable();


    });
});
</script>
```

this is my HTML

```
<div id="lizard" class="dragbal1">
<img id="output2" class="out-put-img2" style="position: absolute;top: 108px;right: 108px" height="80px" width="80px"></div>
```

Comment: First, you will want to avoid switching from `jQuery` and `$`. Second, what is not working?

Comment: I also see that you have posted this same code a number of times over the past few days. You may want to review the answers and comments you have gotten on previous questions before posting a new question.

Comment: Similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41558738/draggable-multiplies-every-time-i-move-it